# Closed formula for the sum $a^1+a^4+a^9...$

Tags: summation, power-series, generating-functions

I'm wondering if there is a closed formula for the sum $a^1+a^4+a^9...$ and more generally $a^{1^n}+a^{2^n}+a^{3^n}...$ for real $a$ and $n$ such that $|a|<1$ and $n>1$.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "closed formula" :P

Comment: @RiversMcForge Without iterated sums or products, but honestly anything easier to evaluate. I feel like it's a Taylor series of something but that doesn't seem like the case since Taylor series powers grow linearly.

Comment: Since this is a special case of the Jacobi theta function, $a + a^4 + a^9 + a^{16} + ... = \vartheta(0; \frac{\ln a}{\pi i})$, I doubt it has a "nice" closed form in terms of "elementary" functions. I can make this into an answer if you want. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function

Answer (score 1):

According to **Jacobi Triple product** formula we have

$$\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(1-x^{2m})(1+x^{2m-1}y^2)\left(1+\frac{x^{2m-1}}{y^2}\right)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}x^{n^2}y^{2n}$$
for $|x|<1$ and $y\neq0$. Then taking $x=a$ and $y=1$ we get  $$\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(1-a^{2m})(1+a^{2m-1}1^2)\left(1+\frac{x^{2m-1}}{1^2}\right)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a^{n^2}1^{2n}$$

$$\implies\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(1-a^{2m})(1+a^{2m-1})^2=2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{n^2}+1$$

$$\implies\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a^{n^2}=\frac{\prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(1-a^{2m})(1+a^{2m-1})^2-1}{2}$$

You can find more things here
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.68.6437&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @SubhrajitBhattacharya:  But that's not the question as asked... right?

Comment: No. But I obtained a a formula using Jacobi Triple product and therefore posted.

Comment: Well, I can generate an unrelated equation using a different principle.  does that mean I should post *that*???!?